# Gulp + Protractor + CucumberJS does not proceed to next scenario when there is an exception on first scenario

Tags: gulp, cucumber, protractor, gulp-protractor

I have gulp config file as below :

```
gulp.task('automation-test', function (callback) {
gulp.src(['.automation/Features/**/*.js'])

    .pipe(angularProtractor({
        'configFile': './automation/automationConf.js',
        'debug': false,
        'autoStartStopServer': false
    }))
    .on('error', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    })
    .on('end', callback); });
```

When I tried to run my test via cmd, I got an exception, and it stopped at that time. Are there any ways to process to another scenario and mark the previous one as failed when there is an exception?